# How to programatically return a json response after executing a custom filter UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: json, spring, security, filter, spring-security

I'm creating a custom filter UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to handle the authentication process. Basically, when the User performs login http post through the REST /login, the custom filter will execute and should respond a json format containing user details and generated token.

My problem is where do i set to respond a json response to the client?
I'm thinking of creating a subclass of SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and set there the json response. Is this a good idea?

Any help will be much appreciated =)

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason for implementing a custom filter instead of just use the spring security configuration to forward to a servlet that produces the json you need?

Comment: @mael: The reason is to override the default j_username/j_password login parameters names. So I changed it to username/password.

Comment: No need to implement your own filter just for that: [_The default parameter names to use are contained in the static fields SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY and SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY. **The parameter names can also be changed by setting the usernameParameter and passwordParameter properties**._](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks @Xaerxess but that is not my initial issue. The issue is in the one i had posted =)

Comment: @mael - one reason is that the Ext-JS, after a form submit expects JSON back, and the forwarding gives it an HTML document.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement your own SuccessHandler and inject it into UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

   public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
       super();
       setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
   }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

           super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
           response.write("my JSON response");
    }


    protected class NoRedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy {

        @Override
        public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
            // no redirect

        }

    }

}
```

Note the NoRedirectStrategy: by default UsernamePassword filter will redirect after a successful logon which you probably dont want in this case. Also note that in the above implementation filter chain is terminated on authentication success - you have to make sure your filter renders the proper response, dont rely on underlying servlet to do it for you.

Alternatively you can leave the redirect in place and send client to another URL which in turn renders the JSON response you are looking for.

Sample security context:

```
    <!--  Security -->
    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/rest/login" filters="wsFilter"/>
        </sec>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wsFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
      <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myAuthenticationManager"/>
      <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="myAuthSuccessHandler"/>
      <property name="passwordParameter" value="pass"></property>
      <property name="usernameParameter" value="user"></property>
      <property name="postOnly" value="false"></property>
   </bean>

       <bean id="myAuthSuccessHandler" class="com.my.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager id="myAuthenticationManager" >
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDetailsImpl">
            <sec:password-encoder hash="md5">
            </sec:password-encoder>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Should that body writing be `response.getWriter().write(...)`?